# Asterisk play announcment at start

Tags: queue, config, asterisk

I have this queue config

```
[1XXX]
musiconhold = default
strategy = ringall
timeout = 30
retry = 1
weight = 0
wrapuptime = 5
maxlen = 0
periodic-announce = /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/xxxx/resources/audio/gsm/waiting_1
periodic-announce-frequency = 15
relative-periodic-announce = yes
announce-holdtime = no
joinempty = yes
ringinuse = false

member => SIP/1001
member => SIP/1002
member => SIP/1003
```

What I cant do is make the waiting_1 announcment to play in begining and for first time not wait the 15 seconds. This is my fist time with AsteriskNOW or Asterisk in particular, so please be straightforward. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices

1) create moh class in which put your announce as you wish(mix sound files),assing that class to queue

2) play announce before queue. unfortanly that will result delay in processing.

Sorrry,no other ways.

Comment: I did the second part. Since requirement was that announcement should play even if agents are free in queue i simply put the Playback before Queue and it was ok because of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sort option in the moh class. And put files with names like 1.wav 2.wav and so on to the directory
this is config file [documentation](http://doxygen.asterisk.org/trunk/Config_moh.html)

example of musiconhold.conf:

```
[announceclass]
mode=files
directory=announce
sort=alpha     ; Sort the files in alphabetical order.
```

after this just create directory announce, copy music files there, and name it like:

```
1.announce.wav
2.wav
3.wav
...
10.wav
...
```

so, the 1.announce.wav will be played first

and choose moh class in queues.conf

```
[q1]
musicclass = announceclass
```

But you should put a lot of files, if you don't want to make your caller to listen announce twice.